# How to integrate VueJS with Django and deploy them

Tags: django, vue.js

I'm beginner in frontend development.

I'm trying to use VueJS for my new Django project. And I'm thinking about how to integrate Vue with Django. I have been looking up and seems like there are two ways to do it.

First way is to include Vue files inside `static/js` folder. (like as we do with jquery) and `templates` is also included inside djnago project.

And the second way is using `webpack` and creating another `frontend` folder outside Django project. templates is included inside Vue components.

My first question is for the second way, how I can deploy the project? For local dev, I need to run Django project and Vue part separately and I'm wondering how I can deploy them later.

Also, which way is better? What is the advantages and disadvantages of each way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project relies only on Django/DRF api, you can deploy your frontend separately.

If your project needs only a Vue component to be displayed on some page, but otherwise takes advantage of Django's renders, you need to include your Vue app into Django project.

Just creating a folder inside `static/js/Vue` to store all related code will be enough in terms of structuring. Then you'll need to integrate your Webpack into Django template. For this you'll find [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) useful. Also [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@michealjroberts/part-1-integrating-django-2-vue-js-and-hot-webpack-reload-setup-387a975166d3).

Comment: Thanks for anwering my question. Can I create the website without Django-webpack-loader? In that case, I neet to deploy the API part and frontend part separately?

Comment: @dude yes, in case of separation of API and frontend it would be deployed separately.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. Is the second way only for creating single page website? If I'm not sure I want to make the website single page, should I avoid the second way's structure?

Comment: @dude second way - using django-webpack-loader - allows rendering bundles in selected templates and has no problems handling multiple vue apps in one template. So for example you can use bundle with 2 components using each of them in 2 different instances of vue on one page (let's say 2 widgets for your dashboard) but not use any on public /index.